# Unrecognized strings while parsing in nested Json in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I could not find any solution to get rid of some information in json data  that I want to get rid of some string or I need to generalized that string that doesn't effect my code while parsing. to be clear, my sample code is

```
{
"0xfc255":{
    "Eczane":"Nural",
    "Eczaci":"MEHMET AYDO\u011eAN",
    "Adres":"Haymana Yolu Caddesi No:86\/A Kar\u015f\u0131yaka",
    "Tarif":"",
    "Telefon":"3124841594",
    "Telefon2":null,
    "Lat":"39.801085082411184",
    "Lng":"32.79844880104065",
    "Sehir":"Ankara",
    "Ilce":"G\u00f6lba\u015f\u0131",
    "Mkk":"Kar\u015f\u0131yaka Mahallesi"
},
"0xfd9a6":{
    "Eczane":"Ta\u015fanlar",
    "Eczaci":"SAL\u0130H U\u011eUR TA\u015eANLAR",
    "Adres":"Atat\u00fcrk Mahallesi  Caddesi No:36\/C",
    "Tarif":"",
    "Telefon":"3122691661",
    "Telefon2":null,
    "Lat":"39.963343555855204",
    "Lng":"32.57991850376129",
    "Sehir":"Ankara",
    "Ilce":"Sincan",
    "Mkk":"Atat\u00fcrk Mahallesi"
},}
```

As you can see dictionary names are not same and I want to create variables like `let adress = json["0xfd9a6"]["Adres"]` so that I can use information.
I want to learn how to get rid of `0xfd9a6` string and parse other variables in json data.

my code is simple

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
    let html = sayfayiGetir(url: "https://......./nobetci-eczaneler.html?json=")
    
    let json = JSON(parseJSON: html)
    parse(json: json)
    
    let adress = json["0xfd9a6"]["Adres"]
}
```

---

## Solved

Finally I found the solution with SwiftyJSON. here is the code what I look for a while:

```
func getJson(){

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://.........nobetci-eczaneler.html?json=") else {return}
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do{
            
            let json = try JSON(data: data)
            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                // Do something you want
                print(subJson["Eczane"])
            }
            
        }catch let jsonErr{
            print(jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Did you try? Show your code

Comment: my code is simple ; override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        let html = sayfayiGetir(url: "https://.........../nobetci-eczaneler.html?json=")
        
        let json = JSON(parseJSON: html)
        parse(json: json)
        
        let adress = json["0xfd9a6"]["Adres"]
        
      

    }

Comment: This type of thing has many answers on here already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D%5Bjson%5Dnested

Comment: my problem is not about how to do parsing or not. my problem is dictionary names are not same. you can see  one is 0xfd9a6 and the other is 0xfc255 and I want to grab data from each dictionary and use same data and show them in tableview. and this dictionaries wil be about 5 to 50 according to city I choose.

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. It's unreadable. Edit your question to include the code.

Comment: I realized and added to main post.

Comment: Are you using a third party library like SwiftyJSON. (What is the function (`JSON(parsJSON:)`. What is the function `sayfayiGetir(url:)`?)

Comment: Are the keys 0xSomething important? Do you want to keep them? You may iterates the dictionaries keeping only the values associated. Or on the values associated add additional key/value with that key as the value. But clearly, you need to show what you want at the end, because it's unclear.

Comment: @DuncanC I m using SwiftyJSON. sayfayiGetir(url:)?) function is for loading website url with json response. there is no problem with that. I m getting json results as I shared in my question with this function.

Comment: @Larme that things come from reference url and I want to get rid of them but no idea how to do that..

Comment: In a dirty way (should be something simpler): `let withoutKeys = json map({$0.values.map{$0}})`, then it's `withoutKeys[0]["Adres"]` or `withoutKeys[1]["Adres"]`. Is that what you want? Show how you want to use it, show the JSON you would love to have.

Comment: thanks @Larme. I think this is what I m looking for. let me try it

Comment: @larme Note that that solution will likely result in getting a different order each time you build the `withoutKeys` array. I was thinking of writing a solution that would map the dictionaries to key/value tuples, sort by key, then strip off the keys. That way at least you get consistent ordering.

Comment: I know, dictionaries are unordered (normal behavior), but I asked twice the author what he/she would like as a result. User might also sort them afterwards according to `Eczaci` (which I guess is a name?) or to long/lat according to his/her current position. Btw your solution to keep the order is still a good idea, algorithmically speaking.

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you posted contains a dictionary of dictionaries. A dictionary can't be used as the data source for a table view since dictionaries are unordered, and a table view requires that the model have a specific order.

You could map your structure to an array of dictionaries but you would need to decide what order to use and what to do about the keys for the outer dictionaries. Perhaps sort the inner dictionaries using the key from the outer dictionary?

If you have a dictionary of dictionaries and you instead want an array of the outer dictionaries, you could simply map to just the values, as in Larme's comment. However, the order of values will be undefined in the resulting array.

I suggest using code like this:

```
let sorted = json.map { $0 } //Map to an array of (key, value) tuples
    .sorted { $0.key < $1.key } //sort the array of tuples by key (the key)
    .map { $0.value } //map the tuples to an array of just the values
```

Comment: my problem is how to reach nested data without using  this kind "0xfd9a6"  strings because this strings are not standart.

Comment: You have a dictionary of dictionaries. You need to fix that. The keys to the outer dictionary are those strange strings you mention.

Comment: they are coming from reference website. and I dont have any idea how to get rid of them.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. The output of that would be an array of the inner dictionaries, sorted by the keys from the website, so they will always be in the same order.

Comment: I found the solution and write to my post. thanks for your effort.

Comment: Your "solution loops through the key/value pairs in your dictionary and prints the value parts, but it doesn't do anything with those values. Also be aware that the output you get from looping through the key/value pairs will be in an an arbitrary order that may be different from one time to the next. The code in my answer converts the output to an array, and will always yield the same order

Comment: I just write print to see if it works and yes it worked. in my main code. I grab values and assign to global variables. and use them in different classes.